# Entity table not created using Entity manager

Tags: jpa

I am trying to insert student data in mysql database using Java Persistence API. My code does not throw any exception. But entity table is not created in database.

Persistence class:

```
public class PersistStudent {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Student_details");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        try
        {
        StudentEntity s = new StudentEntity();
        s.setS_id(101);
        s.setS_name("Ram");
        s.setS_fee("5000");
        em.persist(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

}
```

Entity class:

```
package DEMO.JPA;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="students")
public class StudentEntity {

    @Id
    private int s_id;
    private String s_name;
    private String s_fee;


    public int getS_id() {
        return s_id;
    }
    public void setS_id(int s_id) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
    }
    public String getS_name() {
        return s_name;
    }
    public void setS_name(String s_name) {
        this.s_name = s_name;
    }
    public String getS_fee() {
        return s_fee;
    }
    public void setS_fee(String s_fee) {
        this.s_fee = s_fee;
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
                 version="2.1"> 
    <persistence-unit name="Student_details">  
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>    
        <class>DEMO.JPA.StudentEntity</class>  

    <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
                <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            </properties>

        </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

Console :

> Jul 13, 2019 8:13:53 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper
>   logPersistenceUnitInformation INFO: HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: Student_details   ...] Jul 13, 2019
>   8:13:53 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate
>   Core {5.1.0.Final} Jul 13, 2019 8:13:53 AM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found Jul 13, 2019 8:13:53 AM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist Jul 13, 2019 8:13:53 AM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} Jul 13, 2019 8:13:53 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) Jul 13, 2019 8:13:54 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>   at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa] Jul 13, 2019 8:13:54 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root,
>   password=****} Jul 13, 2019 8:13:54 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false Jul 13, 2019
>   8:13:54 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1) Jul
>   13, 2019 8:13:54 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO:
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect Jul 13,
>   2019 8:13:55 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   stop INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool
>   [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa]

**Is there issue with my configuration in Persistence.xml ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always commit the transaction in order to make the new records to be really inserted into the database. On the other hand , you should rollback the transaction if there are exception.

But now you commit the transaction when there are exception ,and do nothing in the success case. So the transaction does not commit yet for the success case and that 's why no records are really inserted into the database.

Try to revise the your codes to look likes the followings. The point is to commit the transaction at the end:

```
   public static void main(String args[]){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Student_details");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        try{
           StudentEntity s = new StudentEntity();
           s.setS_id(101);
           s.setS_name("Ram");
           s.setS_fee("5000");
           em.persist(s);
           em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
         }finally{
           em.close();
           emf.close();
         }
    }
```